# How to clone git repo using private key

Tags: git, ssh

I have read a few questions and answers on here regarding using ssh to clone a git repo, but none have worked for my scenario.

My setup includes a server with a private git repo that I can pull from locally by running `git pull`. I have a git config file on my local machine that tells it where to pull from. It's been set up like this for a long time.

I now need to pull from that same repo from a different server. I have the same exact `.git/config` on the new server as I do my local.

When I run `git pull` on the new server, I want it to grab files from the current prod git repo just like my local machine does, but it gives me the error:

`ssh: connect to host mysite.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

I would greatly appreciate any help in fixing this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: your remote server has a public key which is associated with your previous local system?

Comment: @dnit13 not sure, I don't recall creating any public keys on my local before running `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

the following error

> ssh: connect to host mysite.com port 22: Connection refused

indicates that the ssh-server on the host `mysite.com` is not reachable on port 22.

here's a number of ideas why:

- there is no ssh-server running at all
- there is an ssh-server running but a firewall is blocking access
- there is an ssh-server running but it is listening on a non-standard port
- you have accidentally mistyped the server-name (or the server-name is resolved to the wrong IP)

Comment: thank you for this. however, I can ssh to the machine from my local computer fine. ssh is running on default port 22.

Comment: @TreyCopeland you can `ssh` **from** the same machine you are running `git pull` on?